# Write unix bash script execute and stop process given certain message

Tags: unix, makefile

I search few examples, I could not find bash script start a process and stop it after certain string

My process look like this

first command:

```
make resetdb && curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/_all && make runsdnlistproc
```

kill process when `list already processed` in ouput

Second command:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices\?v
```

thanks in advance.

---

I've tried with `expect`:

```
expect -c "make resetdb && curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/_all && make runsdnlistproc
expect \"list already processed\" { close }”
```

but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you post the shell-script?

Comment: I got stuck between commands stop and start second command.
echo "delete current list" 
command  make resetdb && curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/_all && make runsdnlistproc

Comment: I tried expect and did not work for me `expect -c "make resetdb && curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/_all && make runsdnlistproc; expect \"list already processed\" { close }”`

Comment: Do you mean that you want curl to download something, but abort if it downloads a certain string? Does this question really pertain to makefiles?

Comment: Indeed, between two commands. I would like stop and start triggered by string 'list already been processed'